# Can't receive object in Asp.Net MVC5 from JSON format

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

There is a JSON sending:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var test = {};
    test.PosX1 = 0;
    test.PosX2 = 10;
    test.PosY1 = 10;
    test.PosY2 = 1;
    test.TemplateId = 0;
formData.append("block", test);
... +some file

var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.post("/Templates/Create", formData,
        {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
            //transformRequest: angular.identity
        })
```

MVC controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Create(string templateName, HttpPostedFileBase file, Models.ModelView.TemplateBlockView block)
    {
```

and I get templateName, file, but I didn't get a block.

Model:

```
   public class TemplateBlockView
    {
        public int PosX1;
        public int PosX2;
        public int PosY1;
        public int PosY2;
        public int TemplateId;
    }
```

Here are the Request Headers:

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----
```

I've tried different Content-Type, but without results.

Comment: Change `headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }` to ` headers: { 'Content-Type': application/json}`